# Unite Linux-project and Windows-project features all-in-one

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio, cross-compiling

Visual Studio 2022 provides you with several project types both for Linux and Windows. You can create native C++ Linux-projects and compile them using WSL or real Linux working on virtual machine. But how can I compile, run and debug cross-platform projects for both Linux and Windows simultaneously switching between these operating systems via Target property in Visual Studio? Are there any built-in solutions different from custom build tools like CMake in Visual Studio?

Comment: Put all common and shared code in a library project, and create two different executable projects (both depending on the common library), one for each target?

Comment: As far as I tested it now this works only for static libraries. What can I do with shared dynamic libraries which are dll's on Windows and so's on Linux?

Comment: Thinking a little more, it's possible to add new targets to the normal list of "Release" and "Debug". Perhaps it's possible to add platform-specific targets there as well? IIRC it used to be possible to do it long long ago (when Windows NT existed for both x86, PPC and Alpha).

Comment: I have found an example with only one project both for Linux and Windows with different property pages (just look at the gif on the web page) https://github.com/micosta/qt_vs_linux__wiggly Works without Qt Visual Studio Addin installed. Looks like they copy-pasted target and configuration properties directly into vcxproj file with notepad.